# Is it possible to guess EAN-13 (or GTIN) based on the owner's prefix and item reference?

Tags: ean-13

Here are some product references from the tires brand "Continental" associated with their corresponding EAN-13 code:

```
REFERENCE_CONTINENTAL   EAN-13
127400                  4019238104899
127600                  4019238104929
127800                  4019238104936
128400                  4019238104967
128800                  4019238104981
129000                  4019238105001
130000                  4019238105094
130400                  4019238105117
132700                  4019238105209
133100                  4019238105223
134500                  4019238105247
136300                  4019238105308
200020                  4019238448832
200021                  4019238453751
200034                  4019238491746
200114                  4019238798784
200115                  4019238798777
200116                  4019238798760
200117                  4019238798753
200118                  4019238798746
240137                  4019238267365
240138                  4019238267372
240141                  4019238312119
240142                  4019238267389
240144                  4019238312126
240151                  4019238364170
240246                  4019238109061
240372                  4019238281712
```

based on http://gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gtin, I understand 4019238 is the prefix of Continental, then comes 5 digits and then comes the validation digit. Assuming that a manufacturer creates new EAN's based on their own product references, is it possible to guess the complete EAN (or GTIN) for other references from Continental? For example:

```
REFERENCE_CONTINENTAL   EAN-13
282038                  ?
282040                  ?
282044                  ?
```

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.  The product part of the EAN (GTIN) code is arbitrarily chosen by manufacturor and there is no need to correspond to a product number in any way.  You simply cannot guess the EAN from a product number.